# Failed to source ~/.bashrc from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my script, I try to source two files to fetch the variables.

But it failed to get the variables defined in `~/.bashrc`.

```
OS: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.2 LTS
```

```sh
$ cat debug.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat > ~/env.sh << EOF
VAR1="123"
EOF

echo "VAR2=456" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/env.sh
source ~/.bashrc

set -u
echo ${VAR1}
echo ${VAR2}
```

```sh
$ ./debug.sh

123
./debug.sh: line 14: VAR2: unbound variable
```

Comment: What's in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Why not just have your shell play Russian Roulette in a game of "Will I start next time?" (dynamic modification of `.bashrc` -- bad idea...) Use a temporary file instead.

Comment: you might give a try replacing `source` with `.` to source the file inside the script...example: `. ~/.env.sh`

Comment: Don't reuse `.bashrc` as a common library. Its purpose is to configure an *interactive* shell. If there is code you want in both a script and in an interactive shell, put that in a 3rd file and source it from both `.bashrc` and your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ubuntu version, .bashrc will check whether it is running interactively, if it is not, it will do nothing. Non-interactive means you called it inside another shell, which you can just comment out the following lines in .bashrc.

`# If not running interactively, don't do anything`

```
case $- in
*i*) ;;
  *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: That check is there for a reason. Don't comment the lines out just so you can force `.bashrc` to be used for a purpose it isn't intended.